# Rails _url helper and force_ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, helper

I have the following in production.rb:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Now, when using

```
path_to_page_url(@record)
```

in an email, the url that is generated looks like this:

https://example.com

which times out.

However, https://www.example.com does not time out.

Is there any way to add the "www" prefix to the url helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in production.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.example.com', protocol: 'https'}
```